# Mysql Cross Join without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to collate data from two similar but unrelated tables into one list.

I can do two separate queries but would prefer to do it in 1, thought Cross Join was the answer but it doesnt give me the info in the right format

Given that both tables have the same structure

```
fields: name,address,type
```

I wanted to select on this and collate into one list

I tried:

```
SELECT table1.name,table1.address,table1.type,
SELECT table2.name,table2.address,table2.type,
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN  table2
```

but this produces a side by side result set where some data is duplicated.

Is there a way to do this so that it produces just one set of data, rather than 2 side by side?

so the end result is one field "name" one "address" and one "type" but data from both tables in there.

Comment: You have an extra `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: If it doesn't put both side by side, why are you joining the tables? Which table's name, address, and type should it use?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` creates a full cartesian product between all the rows, without trying to match elements. Are you sure you're not looking for `NATURAL JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a union so you would get the two tables as one result set but with no duplicates.

```
SELECT table1.name,table1.address,table1.type
FROM table1
union
SELECT table2.name,table2.address,table2.type,
FROM table2
```

Comment: You don't need the outer query. By default `UNION` removes duplicates; you have to use `UNION ALL` to keep duplicates.

Comment: You can also write `UNION DISTINCT` if you want to be explicit.

Comment: Updated, didn't have anything handy to test it on so went with overkill.